# Excel Random Number with Specified Percentage

Tags: excel, random, numbers

I want to make a set of random data with range of 1 to 10.
For now, I'm using:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,10)
```

Question is, how can I make, let say, integer 1 consist 90% of the random data?
So that Cell A1 to A100 have 90% of integer 1 and 10% of any other integer within the range of =RANDBETWEEN().

Comment: What you mean by integer 1? Can you be more specific with your question. Appreciate if you post your data how you want it to be

Comment: By saying integer 1, I mean I want the number to be a whole number without decimal places. For example, I want to assign random numbers to 10 cells with a range of 1 to 10. But, I want to refine the generated numbers so that one of the number (between 1 to 10) covers specified percentage of the sample.

Sample 1 (1 = 90%, other random number = 10%)
A1=1
A2=1
A3=2
A4=1
A5=1
A6=1
A7=1
A8=1
A9=1
A10=1

or

Sample 2 (5 = 50%, other random number = 50%)
A1=5
A2=10
A3=1
A4=5
A5=3
A6=5
A7=5
A8=8
A9=7
A10=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
=MAX(1, RANDBETWEEN(1, 100)-90)
```

Basically you multiply the random range by ten and you assign 90% of it to the number `1`.

Comment: I think you will get 1 in 91% of trials.

Comment: Thanks, but somehow I can't understand the equation completely. If the generated random number is 10, it will be deducted by 90 and we will have =MAX(1, -80) and it will gives value 1. But what if I want to change my desired result to other number and modify the frequency as well?

Comment: @JohnD that's the purpose of the `MAX` part: negative results will be set to 1 :). Therefore, any results below 90 (which occur 90% of the time) will result in 1.

Comment: The new version still has 91% chances of getting 1. I wonder if it is even possible to get what OP is asking for with only one `RANDBETWEEN`. The best I could come up with is a bit shorter version of pnuts answer: `=1+(RANDBETWEEN(1,10)=10)*RANDBETWEEN(1,9)`

Comment: @JohnD OK, for a general approach and a different distribution, that's more complicated, you need to specify precisely the distribution you  want and we can find a formula for that. That would be  a *very interesting* subject for a new question. :)

Comment: I cannot agree, the second version returns 1 for 0,1,..,90 returned by `RANDBETWEEN`, (91 out of 100 cases).

Comment: @BrakNicku Ah, I agree. That looks to me like a misconception or imprecision in the original question. But again, `RANDBETWEEN` is not perfectly uniform anyway ;)

Comment: @JohnD are you sure that you want exactly `90/10` and not `91/9` ? Why do you formulate it as `10% for the other 9 outcomes` and not `1% for each other outcome`?

Comment: @A.S.H It doesn't have to be 90/10. I just want to make my sample data weighted (in term of frequency/percentage) to my desired value instead of completely random.

Comment: In that case the suggested solution is good. To move on the a general solution with different weights for each outcome, I would go for a hidden worksheet where I put my outcomes in a table, each repeated by its weight, and select randomly from the range. I can write the solution in detail for such eventual question :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?

```
=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,10),1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,RANDBETWEEN(2,10))
```

Comment: I thought along the same lines, but came up with `=CHOOSE(IF(RAND()<0.9,1,2),1,RANDBETWEEN(2,10))`